# MessagePack: how to serialize without types information?

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-8.0, msgpack

I try to serialize an object which contains a lists of another objects. I would like to send serialized data to front-end part of my application using SignalR. For serialization I use MessagePack library as a nuget package. My application is written in NET 8 (backend) and frontend uses ReactJS.

I have tried serialize some data this way:

`var serializedData = MessagePackSerializer.Typeless.Serialize(graphic);`

But when I send this data over SignalR and in my browser I could see names of classes inside binary data like on the image below:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnmEM.png)

In this image you could see names like: "FileType", "VectorStyle" etc..
Info about types also leads to an increased file size, because before serialization file size is 4MB and after in my browser I see that sent data is over 5MB

What I want to achieve is to serialize data without any type names.
I would be greatful for any advice or help :)

Comment: I wonder how you intend to *read* that data in your client, if it contains no metadata about its properties.

Comment: If you use [`MemoryPack`](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack) (from the same author) it uses zero-encoding so it doesn't store as much metadata. But beware of the caveats listed in the documentation! You could also look at [`FlatBuffers`](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers). However they do both still store class names, I think.